# Difference for even and odd values for $n$ in the equation system $u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}$ and $u|_{x=0}=0$ and $u|_{x=l}=\sin\frac{n\pi a}lt$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

This is a follow-up question of [What would happen if the boundary value for $u_{tt}=a^2u_{xx}$ is that $u|_{x=0}=0$ and $u|_{x=l}=\sin\frac{n\pi a}lt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220661/428188).

In the following one-dimensional wave equation system:

$$
u=u(x,t),\;\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial t^2}=a^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}
\\
u(0,t) = 0, \; u(l,t) = \sin \omega x
\\
u(x,0) = 0, \; \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, 0) = 0
$$

It is known that [resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) will occur if $\omega$ approaches any of the values $\cfrac {n\pi a}l,\;n=1,2,\ldots$, which are the natural frequencies for the system.

However, my friend worked on the problem and gave a surprising conclusion: When $n$ is an even number, the amplitude of the system will not go up infinitely. Here's part of his proof:

> The solution to the above partial differential equation system is
>
> $$ u(t,x) = \cfrac {\sin\cfrac{\omega x}a}{\sin \cfrac{\omega l}a}\sin\omega t + 2\omega al\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(\omega l)^2-(k\pi a)^2}\sin\cfrac{k\pi at}l\sin\cfrac{k\pi x}l $$
>
> with a little rewriting:
>
> $$ \begin{align} u(t,x) = & \cfrac {\sin\cfrac{\omega x}a}{\sin \cfrac{\omega l}a}\sin\omega t \\&+ \cfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(\omega l)^2-(n\pi a)^2}\sin\cfrac{n\pi at}l\sin\cfrac{n\pi x}l \\&+ 2\omega al\sum_{k=1\\k\ne n}^{+\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(\omega l)^2-(k\pi a)^2}\sin\cfrac{k\pi at}l\sin\cfrac{k\pi x}l \end{align} $$
>
> And when $\omega=\cfrac{n\pi a}t$ is taken into the equation:
>
> $$ u(t,x) = \lim_{y\to n\pi}\left(\cfrac 1{\sin y} + \cfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{y-n\pi}\right)\sin\cfrac{n\pi x}l\sin\cfrac{n\pi at}l \\ + \cfrac{2n}\pi\sum_{k=1\\k\ne n}^{+\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n^2-k^2}\sin\cfrac{k\pi at}l\sin\cfrac{k\pi x}l$$
>
> When $n$ is an even number, there is (Taylor expansion):
>
> $$ \lim_{y\to n\pi}\left(\cfrac 1{\sin y} + \cfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{y-n\pi}\right) = \lim_{y\to n\pi}\cfrac{1+(-1)^{n+1}+o(1)}{y-n\pi+o(y-n\pi)} = 0 \;\textrm{(or }\cfrac{1}{n\pi}\textrm{)} $$
>
> and the infinite part of the sum
>
> $$ \cfrac{2n}\pi\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\cfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n^2-k^2}\sin\cfrac{k\pi at}l\sin\cfrac{k\pi x}l $$
>
> is **bounded**.
>
> Therefore the amplitude will not go all the way to infinity.

I have not been able to reproduce his result:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here, or if my friend's proof is flawed?

Comment: The proposed solution to the PDE satisfies $u(l,t)=\sin(\omega t)$, whereas the original boundary condition is $u(l,t)=\sin(\omega x)$.